# Invalid Image Asset -Top Shelf Image - must be opaque

Tags: tvos

I am getting `ERROR ITMS-90497`, `Invalid Image Asset -Top Shelf Image - must be opaque`, when using this image:

[image: yellow image]

I'm testing with this image to get it working and trying to upload a tvOS application to TestFlight.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The PNG image you're using contains Alpha Channels. Open the image with Preview and go to `File > Export > Uncheck Alpha > Save`.
This will save the image without Alpha Channels.

[image: Uncheck Alpha]

Comment: This worked for me, though certain layers from the same .psd didn't need this treatment. After a bit of trial for each layer it all worked.

Comment: Only the background image should not have alpha. That's why other layers may contain alpha.