# tvOS Icon-Set template

Tags: xcode, tvos, xcode7.1beta

For a tvOS app I am trying to set up the App Icon. First xCode complained about the size and now about the image's alpha.

> /var/folders/fc/s3m4kgtn2gs977m4k8x2s2xm0000gn/T/Large-AppIcon-Scratch-4AC4A1D7-D8F5-4D58-8667-A11E4F2DE7DA.xcassets:
>   The last image stack layer with content, "Back", must be a fully
>   opaque bitmap. The pixel at position (0, 0) has an alpha value of 212.

Are there any easy instructions, tools, or templates which can be used to create a proper `App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets` ?

(without Photoshop CC!)

Comment: To fix your alpha issue: [Invaild Image Asset -Top Shelf Image - must be opaque](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32842850/2108547).

Answer (score 1):

Bohemian Coding's [Sketch](http://www.sketchapp.com) is a great tool to use. If you don't want to spend $100, you can simply use a program like Paint.

> For the small icon, each layer should be 659x371.
>
> For the large icon, each layer should be 1977x1113. (3x the size of the small icon).

The bottom layer cannot have any transparency, but the top two need to have transparency.

Also be sure to leave plenty of buffer room around the outside of your icon.

Comment: Where did you get those weird sizes from? The HIG mentions totally different numbers for app icons.

Comment: Those numbers are totally wrong

Comment: @Fattie this answer was from 2015, the sizes have certainly changed since then. Please consult the Apple docs for the current numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this issue for a while. Finally it dawned on my that Layer 0 can have transparency but Layer 1 cant. With that said, I thought Layer 0 would of been the background and Layer 1 in the foreground, but its the opposite. Layer 0 is the closest to you, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions can be found in the [Apple TV Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/#app-icon). There is also a link to download [resource templates](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/resources/#icon-and-image-templates) including templates for both app icons and the topshelf image.

If you provide an opaque back layer for the app icons then your problem should disappear.

You can use any tool of choice, preferably one that is able to import .psd files (the templates are in .psd format). Personally I use Pixelmator. AFAIK GIMP also supports importing .psd files.