# tvOS; Launch Image doesn't appear on launch

Tags: xcode, tvos, xcasset

I'm developing an tvOS app, and I'm trying to set the LaunchImage.

I've added a .pgn-file with size 1920 × 1080 called LaunchImage.pgn to Assets.xcassets, by dragging the file from finder to the LaunchImage image-socket in xcode. But the Launch Image doesn't appear when i launch the app.

[image: screenshot from assest.xcassets]

---

In the target settings, under general:

[image]

---

From the Contents.json-file in /project-folder/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage:

[image]

---

I have tried cleaning the build folder, made a clean build, tried with different files with different filenames.

**Any clues?**

This seems a bit buggy, maybe someone has found a workaround?

Comment: Your PNG image may contain alpha channels, [Invalid Image Asset -Top Shelf Image - must be opaque](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32842850/2108547).

Comment: The PNG has 100% opacity.

Comment: I just tried the method from the link, and it actually solved the problem.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I used Sketch to export the PNG. I exported a bitmap copy of a screenshot from the simulator, and it must have had some alpha channels. I didn't get any warnings in xcode.

I followed the solution presented in this post, and it solved the problem:
[Export PNG without alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834660/invalid-image-asset-top-shelf-image-must-be-opaque/32842850#32842850)

Thanks Daniel! :)